# how can I deploy multiple django cms projects under same domain.I am using apache 2.2 and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, cpanel, mod-wsgi

I need to deploy two Django Cms projects under the same domain name. I need to retrieve the two sites when calling the following domain.
http://rndbkw.tk
http://rndbkw.tk/blog

I have two wsgi configurations included in the httpd.conf

for http://rndbkw.tk

```
ServerName rndbkw.tk
WSGIDaemonProcess rnd python-path=/home/rndbkw/djangocms:/home/rndbkw/virtualenv2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
WSGIProcessGroup rnd
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rndbkw/djangocms/rnd/wsgi.py

ServerName rndbkw.tk
WSGIDaemonProcess blog python-path=/home/rndbkw/projects/djangocms:/home/rndbkw/projects/virtualenv2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
WSGIProcessGroup blog
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rndbkw/projects/djangocms/rnd/wsgi.py
```

But i cannot get back http://rndbkw.tk/blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems with your configuration of:

```
ServerName rndbkw.tk
WSGIDaemonProcess rnd python-path=/home/rndbkw/djangocms:/home/rndbkw/virtualenv2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
WSGIProcessGroup rnd
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rndbkw/djangocms/rnd/wsgi.py

ServerName rndbkw.tk
WSGIDaemonProcess blog python-path=/home/rndbkw/projects/djangocms:/home/rndbkw/projects/virtualenv2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
WSGIProcessGroup blog
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rndbkw/projects/djangocms/rnd/wsgi.py
```

Instead use:

```
ServerName rndbkw.tk

WSGIDaemonProcess blog python-home=/home/rndbkw/projects/virtualenv2.7 python-path=/home/rndbkw/projects/djangocms
WSGIScriptAlias /blog /home/rndbkw/projects/djangocms/rnd/wsgi.py process-group=blog application-group=%{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess rnd python-home=/home/rndbkw/virtualenv2.7 python-path=/home/rndbkw/djangocms
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rndbkw/djangocms/rnd/wsgi.py process-group=rnd application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

Changes made were:

- Mount blog at sub URL of `/blog`.
- Move the `WSGIScriptAlias` for `/blog` before that for `/` so that it takes precedence, else that for `/` will always match first and nothing will ever get through the the blog site.
- Per best practice, use `python-home` of `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive to specify the location of the virtual environment instead of adding `site-packages` using `python-path`.
- Use `process-group` option to `WSGIScriptAlias` to indicate which daemon process group to use. This makes it more precise. Your use of `WSGIProcessGroup` wouldn't have worked as wasn't qualified to a `Location` or `Directory` scope so whichever of the two `WSGIProcessGroup` directives was last would have overridden the first.
- Set `application-group`to `%{GLOBAL}` to force use of main interpreter context of each daemon process. This solves problems with some third party extension modules for Python that will not work in sub interpreter contexts.

Comment: I used the same configuration it will be worked fine.But when i am login to rndbkw.tk/blog. After signing it will be redirecting to the rndbkw.tk. I don't know what is going to b happen. And when i am removing the rndbkw.tk then rndbkw.tk/blog appear in browser without style.What thing is going to wrong?Please help me..

Comment: Unless you should your actual mod_wsgi configuration so it can be verified that it is correct, is impossible to say. Also show what you have set the login URL setting to in Django settings. Do not do this here though, go ask a new question describing your problem. You shouldn't ask questions about your problems against old questions.

Answer (score 1):

The last line in your configuration needs to be

```
WSGIScriptAlias /blog /home/rndbkw/projects/djangocms/rnd/wsgi.py
```